# How do you use browser.element to find elements that are not yet visible on the page?

Tags: nightwatch.js

I want to use browser.element nightwatch function to find elements that are not yet visible on the page. If I use waitForElementVisible that throws an error. browser.element seems like the best way to find an element because it does not through an error, but sometimes the element is not visible.

Comment: What error is it throwing? What code have you tried?